mounting node project directory with docker compose for easy development/live reload
I am trying to develop a node/express/react/redis project with docker compose, and I want to be able to see my code changes in react (frontend) without having to take down the containers and rebuild them. To do so, I am trying to mount my node project directory in that container, so any changes made will carry over into the container.
I am currently getting the following error, when i try to run docker-compose up --build --remove-orphans:
npm error enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'

Here is my current directory structure (irrelevant folders/files omitted for clarity):
my_project/
-backend/
-frontend/
--app/
---node_modules/
---public/
---src/
---package-lock.json
---package.json
--Dockerfile
-compose.yml

Here is my_project/compose.yml:
services:
  cache:
    container_name: my_project-redis
    restart: always
    image: redis
    command: redis-server --requirepass SWIPERNOSWIPING
    networks:
      - net-backend
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  backend:
    container_name: my_project-api
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=cache
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
      - REDIS_PASS=SWIPERNOSWIPING
      - API_PORT=3001
    depends_on:
      - cache
    networks:
      - net-backend
      - net-frontend

  frontend:
    container_name: my_project-ui
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/app:/app
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - PORT=8080
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - net-frontend

networks:
  net-backend:
  net-frontend:


and here is my_project/frontend/Dockerfile:
# frontend/Dockerfile
FROM node:18-alpine
ENV PORT=${PORT}
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install
EXPOSE ${PORT}
CMD ["npm", "start"]

What in the world am I doing wrong? Is this an issue with my config, or a docker cache of some sort that I haven't cleared properly?

Especially if you're working on the frontend, can you start the dependencies in containers (docker-compose up -d backend), and then use ordinary Node without Docker to develop the frontend?  Overwriting your image contents with volumes: can lead to problems where nothing in your image gets used at all, and so for example the node_modules directory will be missing or incorrect in your setup.
